# Drawing the subgroup lattice of D10

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

I've been tasked with drawing a subgroup lattice of the dihedral group of order 10. I know from Lagrange's theorem that non-trivial subgroups must have order 2 or 5. Finding the subgroups of order 2 is straightforward, since there can be only one element besides the identity, but what about the groups of order 5? I could feasibly brute-force my way through this problem by going through the elements of $D_{10}$ one by one and trying to construct groups of order 5, but there must be a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $5$ is a prime number, groups of order $5$ are cyclic.  So you should find all the elements of order $5$ in $D_{10}$ and then determine what subgroups they generate.

Note that any non-identity element of a cyclic group of order $5$ generates that group.  So if an element of order $5$ is contained in a subgroup that you have already found, then it generates that subgroup and you do not need to check it again.

Comment: So subgroups of prime order are always cyclic? Why is that?

Comment: Any group of prime order is cyclic.  If $|G| = p$ is prime and $g \in G$ then the cyclic group $\langle g\rangle$ generated by $g$ is a subgroup of $G$.  It's order must therefore divide the order of $G$ so it can have order $1$ or order $p$.  If $g$ is the identity element it will have order $1$.  If $g$ is not the identity element then it will have order $p$, which gives $\langle g\rangle = G$.

Comment: Ah, that's a very useful result! Thanks. But what would I have done if the order had not been a prime? For example, $D_{12}$ would have subgroups of order 6, which need not be cyclic. What would be an efficient method for finding those subgroups?

Comment: Well, the abelian ones are still cyclic, so you'd start by finding those.  As $3$ divides $6$ any group of order $6$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $3$.  So I would find all those and then for each one figure out if there's an element of order $2$ that I can add to the generating set without generating the entire group.

Comment: In general finding all subgroups of a given order is tedious and the way one goes about it can be somewhat ad-hoc.  There's not really a "best" way to do it that works in all cases.