# Listing all subgroups of $D_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

My work so far:

The cyclic subgroups are trivial to find. They are simply rotations generated from $\langle r^d\rangle$ where $d\mid10$. So $d=1,2,5,10$.

$\langle r \rangle= \{e,r, r^2, \dots, r^9 \}$

$\langle r^2 \rangle= \{e, r^2, r^4, r^6, r^8 \}$

$\langle r^5 \rangle= \{e, r^5 \}$

$\langle r^{10} \rangle= \{e\}$

The dihedral groups are giving me trouble. I've read [Theorem 3.1 and Example 3.6](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAAahUKEwiw2sLD3pPGAhXFBiwKHcwaAHI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F%7Ekconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fdihedral2.pdf&ei=nNZ_VbCcC8WNsAHMtYCQBw&usg=AFQjCNExft8iJ2-3luuioMN8NO5LaOhJVg&bvm=bv.96041959,d.bGg) of Keith Condrad's notes and I don't understand how to use the index he's referring to. He states that I can generate all the dihedral subgroups of $D_{10}$ from the following: $\langle r^d, r^{i}s\rangle$ where $d\mid 10$ and $0\leq i \leq d-1$ with index $d$.

For example, I understand that a reflection paired with the identity element will form a subgroup. So these would be $\{e,s\}, \{e,rs\}, \{e,r^s\},\dots, \{e,r^9s\}$.

At the moment, my understanding of what he's writing is since there are no rotations in thsse subgroups, $d$ would need to be $0$ in $\langle r^d, r^{i}s\rangle$, so I'd have $\langle e, r^{i}s\rangle$. But if $d=0$, then $0\leq i\leq d-1$ would be $0\leq i\leq -1$, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There should be more cyclic subgroups, namely the ones generated by a reflection.

Comment: $d=0$ will give the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$ that has only the identity..

Comment: A good way of thinking about dihedral subgroups is that by ignoring some angles of $n$-polygon, you can always treat it like a $n/d$-polygon where $d$ divides $n$. For instance, $n=6$ is the symmetry group of a honeycomb cell (hexagon), but if you cut off three angles, you cut a hexagon into a triangle. The symmetry group of regular triangle is naturally embedded inside that of the hexagon.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I was able to work out the notation. I misunderstood Keith's notes and assumed that 1. in Theorem 3.1 was for all the cyclic subgroups and 2. was all the dihedral ones. I've corrected that misunderstanding and will answer my own question.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/582629/104041).